# Azure Tomcat Deployment Path

Tags: java, azure, tomcat

I am deploying a Java application on Tomcat Azure using the Azure Web app.

1. What's the root of Azure Tomcat - Is it `D:\home\site\wwwroot` or `D:/home/site/wwwroot?`
2. If an app is deployed on the root, what will be the path of the app in the Azure Tomcat?  Is it `D:\home\site\wwwroot\<artifact-name>`?

Comment: Hi, have my answer solved your doubts?

Answer (score 0):

1.

> What's the root of Azure Tomcat - Is it `D:\home\site\wwwroot` or
>   `D:/home/site/wwwroot`?

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot
```

2.

> If an app is deployed on the root, what will be the path of the app in
>   the Azure Tomcat? Is it `D:\home\site\wwwroot\<artifact-name>`?

Your application will be deployed under `wwwroot` by default.

Comment: When I see the logs, it is deployed under D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\ROOT\ Can you please confirm as I referring the endpoints based on this path?

Comment: @hawkbase How did you deploy it? Upload .war file?

Comment: Yes, it's deployed as war file

Comment: Using Azure Webapp it’s deployed as a war file using Java and Tomcat

Comment: @hawkbase Yeah, it is different from others. For example, if you have a react app, just deploy to wwwroot is ok. But for war files, it will deploys to `/home/site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT` by default. For more details, you can take a look of this: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-WAR-files-using-wardeploy

Comment: @hawkbase Have any other doubts?

Comment: Thanks very much @Bowman . This worked home/site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT.

Comment: If my solution help you, can you mark it as the answer os the question? It will help others.

Comment: tick the tick left the answer

Comment: @hawkbase https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top This is the tutorial about how to mark the answer.